# Toggle sorting in List View

Tags: json, list, sorting, swiftui, toggle

I use 'Api' as an ObervableObject and inside there's @Published var isAscd to be toggled. Function getPost fetch JSON data from web and populate is List View. I use a button in HeaderView to toggle the sorting method. Compiling is succeeded but button takes no action. I don't know what goes wrong?

```
class Api: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts: [Post] = []
    @Published var isAscd: Bool = false

    func getPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: getListURLString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(posts)
            }



        }
        .resume()
    }

}


struct HeaderView: View {

    var holding: String = "市值/數量"
    var earning: String = "現價/成本"
    var profit: String = "持倉賺蝕"
    @ObservedObject var api = Api()



    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Button(action: {
                self.api.isAscd.toggle()
                if self.api.isAscd {
                    self.api.posts.sort { $0.stockcode > $1.stockcode}
                } else { self.api.posts.sort { $0.stockcode < $1.stockcode}

                }
                print(self.api.posts.count)
                print(self.api.isAscd)


            }.......}

    List {

                Section(header: HeaderView())

                {
                    ForEach(posts)
                    { post in

                        HStack {

                            VStack(alignment: .leading)

..........

                    }
                }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 250, alignment: .center)

                .onAppear {
                        Api().getPosts {(posts) in
                            self.posts = posts
                            //self.apr.isAscd.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You sort `rows` but iterates `ForEach(posts)`, and there is no in code any join between `rows` and `posts`. Would you elaborate more in this?

Comment: I update rows with posts and I got the same result. I also found in debug view that the api.posts.count is 0 and api.isAscd toggled irregularly .

Comment: Move the code to sort your results into the view model (your `Api` class). The `isAscd` field should be a `@Published` property on the view model as well. This will allow you to drive the UI (i.e. display a different icon on the sort button). Introduce a new array on `Api` and set up a Combine pipeline that observes the `isAscd` property and produces a sorted array. All of this should go into the `Api` class.

Comment: Thanks ! I've moved sorting code under Api. How should I code within the Button action?

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the new code, @BennyChen?